# How to explore and edit manually and directly a database entry which is hosted in azure web sites? ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

In visual studio, when we use local db, we can explore the database tables and therefore edit or delete any entry manually and directly. How to do the same thing in a website which is already deployed to the azure web sites?

I am currently having problem in one or two rows data, which referes to some invalid data. I could fix it easily by removing the rows, but I don't know how to do so. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which Database are you using in your website in Azure Webiste?
For Azure Table Storage, you can use Azure Storage Explorer. http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/
For SQL Azure, use SSMS. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-manage-azure-ssms/

Comment: hmm, sorry I am just a newbie. I used the databse that is created when I create the web site. It must be something very basic. is it the sql azure?

Comment: Yes. If you're using LocalDB on your dev machine, it will use SQL azure after publishing. You can config database connection in publish profile. If you just create a empty website, the db will be not configed.